# Concatenating Bits in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am developing a software for convolution encoder and bit puncturing.

So in my program a 55 bit length data is generated in every loop. It is stored in the first 55 bits of unsigned long long type variable. After every iteration I have to transfer these 55 bits into a buffer of unsigned char (Buffer is quite large say around 500 Bytes). The bits must be continuously stored in this buffer. (i.e no gaps). Is there some bit trick to concatenate like this easily?

Comment: Can you change the data types you're working with?

Comment: Can you use a [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)?

Comment: I'm not aware of any easy trick. You must either use some kind of bit-packing data structure, or assemble the bits oldskool style.

Comment: @adam10603 If it helps with this problem, I can.

Comment: @NathanOliver Trouble with bitset is that it's fixed size and not easy to convert back to a long array of bytes, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Two solutions comes in my mind. 1) Use `std::vector<bool>`, which is supposed to condensate information and guarantee storage continuity. Howrver you don't know the order in which the bits are stored. Or, 2) write your own class to do that, but obviously not a trick

Comment: Inside a struct, you can specify the exact length of a variable in bits, if that helps. So that way, you have a data type that is exactly 55 bits long. This is not a complete solution in itself, but can be useful.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html Look at function `to_block_range`

Comment: @NathanOliver,
Yes I could use std::bitset to save my 55 bits. But I still want it to be transferred to char buffer. I cannot change the type for that. So I would want a nice way of converting it back to long array of bytes.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I did not immediately understand that function. I am very new to C++. All these years I have been a matlab developer. Would you mind explaining a little bit more for me. I did not understand what that iterator is.

Comment: If you create as this type: `dynamic_bitset<unsigned char>`, and call `to_block_range(mybitset, my_uchar_pointer);` I believe this should work.

Comment: since you're getting the data from an encoder, may i ask if you're reading it directly, ie. by polling a DIO or through an ISR?

Comment: I posted an answer with a class I wrote a while ago. I think it can do just the thing you want! It can accept `uint64_t` as input, store any amount of bits from it (even 55 if you desire), then it can give back all the stored bits chopped up into 1-byte pieces (series of `char`s!), if you want to. Check it out, I think it would work for you.

Comment: [RakNets' BitStream implementation](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/GamePracticum/Raknet/Doc/html/_bit_stream_8cpp_source.html) is maybe worth a look

Comment: @wonkorealtime I am implementing the software encoder, it is not being read from hardware. Here 55 bit example is from one of the code rate 8/11. So I encode 5 bytes of data in one operation to obtain 55 bits. 
Thanks I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: It was correctly pointed out to me that, because I'm aliasing the char-buffer through a `uint64_t*`, I am violating the strict aliasing rule, and am also vulnerable to bugs due to differences in endianness. Nevertheless, if you have certain guarantees about your platform, this might still work. It can be resolved by having a buffer of 64-bit elements though, instead of single bytes.**

In case you want a barebone algorithm that does not depend on any external libraries, you could use the snippet below. Note that bitset is only used to display the result and make sure that it works.

As a test, I defined a 55-bit pattern consisting of 54 consecutive 1's, followed by a 0. The remaining 9 bits in the 64-bit value (`x`) are also zeros. The buffer is a 500-byte character-array, which I aliased in a`uint64_t*`. The algorithm keeps track of the current 64-bit block (`currentBlock`) and the current bit within this block (`currentBit`). It does the following:

1. Shift the bitpattern such that it starts at the current bit-position.
2. OR the result with the current 64-bit block. This means that the first part of the bit-pattern is concatenated to whatever is left of the current block. For example, in the second iteration when the first 55 bits of the first block are filled, the remaining 9 bits will be occupied.
3. Update the `currentBit` variable.
4. Check if the `currentBlock` was overflowed, if so move to the next block and concatenate the remainder of the 55-bitpattern.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <bitset> // only used for testing, not for the algorithm
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       size_t nBits = 55;

       // 54 1's, followed by 10 0's
       uint64_t x = 0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000;

       // 500 byte buffer:
       char buf8[500]{};
       uint64_t *buf = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&buf8[0]);

       // This would be better; use this if possible
       // uint64_t buf[100];

       int currentBit = 0;
       int currentBlock = 0;

       // concatenate the 55-bitpattern 10 times 
       for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
       {
           buf[currentBlock] |= (x >> currentBit);

           currentBit += nBits;
           if (currentBit >= 64)
           {
               ++currentBlock;
               currentBit %= 64;

               buf[currentBlock] |= x << (nBits - currentBit);
           }
       }

       // TEST
       for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
           cout << bitset<64>(buf[i]) << '\n';
   }
   ```

You should probably generalize this and encapsulate it in a function. This is up to you. The program as is produces the following output:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Note the 0's marking every 55'th bit.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` = bad. Works on your compiler, may even work on his compiler. But not guaranteed.

Comment: @NeilKirk Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it says in the standard that it is permitted to cast a `char*` to any other pointer type. EDIT: I was confused with aliasing through a `char*` instead of the other way around... so my code does not obey the strict aliasing rule.... damn

Comment: Lots of things are permitted but don't always work the way you expect. The result stored in `buf8` will be different between little and big endian machines.

Comment: If we're going to talk big/little endian, bit-manipulation get's tricky by definition.... You could check and correct for this though.

Comment: If you use bitwise operations only it will work as expected. The problem is pointer casting or unions.

Comment: You're right... Didn't think of that. I'll leave it to the OP to decide if this solution suits his needs. He might have guarantees about his target platform.

Comment: That's fine, I've made platform assumptions from time to time, but best to put a note in your answer :)

Comment: Yes that sounds good to me! Although I'm not sure about the strict aliasing, that's not my area of expertise.

Comment: You're not supposed to alias pointers through anything but a `void*` or `char*`. I'm aliasing through a `uint64_t*`, which violates this rule.  At least, that's how I understand it works. There's a nice cppcon talk on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd8MI4b_AUc

Comment: @JorenHeit Thanks for this. I now know about "reinterpret_cast". 
There needs a small correction though, because of the OR operation the char buffer must be initialized to zero. 
I tried it with a different pattern "FF00FF00FF00FF00" and I think the order of bits that go into the char buffer is reversed. But no matter I get the idea. Thanks a lot

Comment: I will discuss with my colleague about whether the project has to be portable or not. If it has to then I will do the old school way of assigning byte by byte and shifting appropriately.
Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: @Shreyes You are very welcome. You can make it portable by using an array of `uint64_t`, in which case you don't need the cast anymore. If you need a byte array later, you can cast to `char*` or `unsigned char*`  without violating strict aliasing. Also, the array is initialized to zeros when using the empty brace-initializer. But you're right, this is required for the OR to work accordingly.

Comment: @JorenHeit I got a compiler error for that empty brace statement. I had to "char buf8[500] = {};". There was no equals sign.

Comment: Ah right, that's a C++11 feature. Sorry, I got so used to being able to use C++11, I think everyone is...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this class a while ago when I needed to deal with bits. It might be useful to you as well. Here it is:

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class bitStream {
public:
    bitStream() {}

    /// Copies the data from another bitStream into this one upon construction
    bitStream(const bitStream& bStream, bool reverse=false) {
        this->appendData(bStream, reverse);
    }

    /// Copies the data from a vector of booleans upon construction
    bitStream(const vector<bool>& vec, bool reverse=false) {
        this->appendData(vec, reverse);
    }

    /// Appends data to the stream from a uint64_t type. The lower-n bits will be appended, starting with the highest bit of those by default.
    void        appendData(uint64_t data, size_t n, bool reverse=false) {
        deque<bool> _buffer;
        n = (n>64)?64:n;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            _oneBit tmp;
            tmp.data = data;
            _buffer.push_back(tmp.data);
            data >>= 0x1;
        }
        if (!reverse) std::reverse(_buffer.begin(), _buffer.end());
        for (const auto v: _buffer) _data.push_back(v);
    }

    /// Appends data to the stream from a C-style array of booleans
    void        appendData(bool* data, size_t n, bool reverse=false) {
        if (reverse) {
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) this->appendBit(*(data+(n-i-1)));
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) this->appendBit(*(data+i));
        }
    }

    /// Appends data to the stream from a vector of booleans
    void        appendData(const vector<bool>& vec, bool reverse=false) {
        if (reverse) {
            for (auto i = vec.size()-1; vec.size() > i; --i) this->appendBit(vec.at(i));
        } else {
            for (const auto& v : vec) this->appendBit(v);
        }
    }

    /// Appends a single bit
    void        appendBit(bool bit) {
        _data.push_back(bit);
    }

    /// Appends the bits from another bitStream object to this one
    void        appendData(const bitStream& bStream, bool reverse=false) {
        if (!bStream.getSize()) return;
        if (reverse) {
            for (int i=0; i<bStream.getSize(); i++) this->appendBit(*(bStream.getData()+(bStream.getSize()-i-1)));
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<bStream.getSize(); i++) this->appendBit(*(bStream.getData()+i));
        }
    }

    /// Returns a pointer to the begining of the data (read-only!)
    const bool* getData() const { return &_data.front(); }

    /// Reference to the bit at a specified position (assignable, but at lest n+1 elements must exist before calling!)
    bool& operator[] (size_t n) {
        if (n>_data.size()-1) throw runtime_error("Out of range!");
        return _data.at(n);
    }

    /// Fills your vector with the data chopped up into "sizeof(T)"-byte pieces.
    template <typename T>
    void        getDataAsVector(vector<T>& vec) {
        vec.clear();
        size_t oSize = sizeof(T)*8;
        T tmp = 0x0;
        for (int i=0; i<_data.size(); i++) {
            if (!(i%oSize) && i) {
                vec.push_back(tmp);
                tmp = 0x0;
            }
            tmp <<= 0x1;
            tmp |= _data[i];
        }
        vec.push_back(tmp);
    }

    /// Returns the number of bits that are stored
    size_t      getSize() const { return _data.size(); }

    /// Reverses the stored bits
    void        reverse() { std::reverse(_data.begin(), _data.end()); }
private:
    deque<bool> _data;
    struct _oneBit {
        uint8_t data:1;
    };
};
```

It's fairly trivial to use, so I didn't bother writing an example.

First of all, I never actually ended up using it in a project, so there might be some bugs in there (I remember only testing it very briefly), plus it's not finished completely (there are a couple of possible constructors that I haven't implemented). Also, despite the name "stream", it has nothing to do with what a stream is in C++.

So basically it lets you store bits. The bits you put in it, will be stored at contiguous memory addresses (yes, that's one bit per byte of memory, but whatever), which stay the same for the lifetime of the object (this is because a `deque` doesn't reallocate itself unlike a `vector`)! You can append bits to it in various ways (from different data sources, in reversed or non-reversed order), and read them back in different forms as well. In your case, the `appendData(uint64_t data, size_t n, bool reverse=false)` function is the one you can use to fill it up. To get your data back, you can have a `vector<char>` filled up with the data chopped into 1-byte pieces (characters), if you want it to!

Again, please don't take this as a 100% tested and working thing. I only tested it briefly, so you should try it out and see if it works for you! I thought I'd share it with you, in case you find it helpful.

Comment: I thought he wanted to store it as 1 bit per bit, rather than byte. I don't see this implementation do that anywhere... am I overlooking something?

Comment: Internally it stores them in separate bytes, yes. But you can ask it to fill up a vector of any type with the bits following each other! So you can have your data in that way if you want to. Internally it's not stored that way, but why would you care? Call getDataAsVector() to fill up a vector<char> or something, and it will "compress" the bits together into chars, and fill the vector with as many chars as needed, and there you go. That's pretty much what the OP asked for.

Comment: @adam10603 Thanks will have a look at it.

Comment: Ah right I see. Pretty nice, but it would cause quite some overhead that you wouldn't have otherwise. Both in memory (factor 8 more memory consumption, plus the size of the vector you return whenever you need the consecutive array) and in performance due to the need to generate the compressed version.

Comment: I know, but in the scenario I had when I wrote this, neither of those mattered. I'm hoping the OP doesn't care about those either.